# Unknown error in Google Cloud Functions with Python Script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, google-analytics-api

Trying to run a Python script that I uploaded to cloud functions. I'm running the test and getting unknown error from cloud functions. The script runs fine locally. I've included a requirements.txt file that has the dependencies and a json file the the script needs for authentication. Has anyone else had a similar problem? Is there any way I can get a more helpful error message so I can diagnose the problem?

Edit:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from mysql.connector import errorcode


def main(data, context):

    # MySQL
    DB_NAME = 'GA_Data1'
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user1, password=password1,
                                  host=hostip, database=DB_NAME)
```

Trying to run this script in google functions. I see the actual error now which is at the last line in the code above. It's saying it can't connect to SQL. I think it might be because google's machine's IP address isn't white listed. I've been spending all morning working with google VPCs and trying to assign IP addresses to no avail. I'm not familiar with the google cloud suite at all so this has been very haphazard.

- [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBsrt.png)
- [error when calling gcloud function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHAxV.png)
- [requirements.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoUN2.png)

Comment: Take some time to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the documentation. Post a minimum, reproducible example of the code you are using or what you've tried so far to increase the possibility of the community to engage with your post. How are you running the tests? From the console? Using the [`gcloud functions call method`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call)

Comment: Can you share a minimal code that fail?

Comment: @DanielOcando I've added some code. I also am running the rests using the web browsers, "test function" button in my google cloud function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Notice that since Cloud Functions is a serverless product, each IP would be different and if your database requires some a sort of IP whitelisting this solution won't work (as you'd need to whitelist all the IP ranges related to Google's netblocks, which is very unsafe, since an attacker could simply create any GCP project and hit your database through that means).

Comment: My recommendations would be either to migrate the MySQL database to Cloud SQL or to either use a Computer Engine instance with an [static External IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and run your code from there.

Comment: @DanielOcando Thanks for the suggestions. I'm actually using google cloud SQL. However, the code I have above still works with the cloud database. I actually tried using the static External IP address with cloud NAT. Then whitelisting that IP in the cloud SQL settings. But I'm still getting the same can't connect to database error that I provided pictures of.

Comment: I also added a picture of the error I get when running the function from the command line

Comment: Oh great! Then I guess it could be an issue with the exact dependency you are using MySQL.connetor. I would strongly advise you to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions) carefully, as a code snippet for Python is also provided using sqlalchemy. Notice that the NAT step won't be necessary. Report back if you get any errors at the steps provided on the shared doc.

Comment: @DanielOcando I've got through the first steps of the doc you shared. However the sample python code I'm not too sure of. I just tested my python script locally and it updates the cloud SQL well. I've attached a copy of my requirements file could it be a problem with that? I kinda of randomly added stuff to that that I thought I would need.

Comment: @Andrew Marotta I understand that you'd prefer to use this [library](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/#files) to make the connection. Have you tried changing your connector to `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user1, password=password1, host=hostip, database=DB_NAME, use_pure=True)`. Notice that [as of version 8.0.11 this library uses a C extension by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext.html) that might not be installed on the Cloud Functions Python runtime.